# SFINAE based traits implementation issue with function template overload

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, traits, sfinae

I'm learning aboiut SFINAE and traits and I know that I can define SFINAE-baed traits (traits that use SFINAE in their implementation). A classic implementation of a trait that detects if a type is default constructible is:

```
template <typename T>
struct IsDefaultConstructibleH
{
private:
    template <typename U, typename = decltype(U())>
    //template <typename U, const U& = U()>   // WHY IS THIS ALWAYS SFINAE'd out?
    static TrueType Test(void*);
    template <typename>
    static FalseType Test(...);
public:
    using Type = decltype(Test<T>(nullptr));
};

template <typename T>
struct IsDefaultConstructible : IsDefaultConstructibleH<T>::Type
{
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool IsDefaultConstructibleV = IsDefaultConstructible<T>::Value;
```

As I pointed out in the code above, if I use the commented-out template parameterization clause (and comment-out the one above it), if I run this code:

```
#include "traits.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Default
{
public:
    Default() : mData(10) {}
private:
    int mData;
};

class NoDefault
{
public:
    NoDefault(int i) : mData(i) {}
private:
    int mData;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsDefaultConstructible<Default>::Value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsDefaultConstructibleV<NoDefault> << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the result is always false false, whereas if I use the other parameterization clause (the one which is not commented out) the program gives true, false, as expected. So why does the clause with a non-type parameter always get SFINAE'd out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference types as non-type template parameters *must* be the name of an object with linkage (usually a global variable). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments. It specifically cannot be a temporary.

Thus `const U& = U()` is always invalid in a template, as `U()` isn't the name of a variable (It should look like `const U& = some_global_U_variable`) so it won't be chosen  in `Test<T>(nullptr)`.